# How to upload an app to Windows store using command line

Tags: powershell, command-line, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have created a windows store app and associate it with the store using the Visual Studio IDE. In the Visual Studio IDE there are menu options to create App packages and upload App Packages.

[image: Menu Option]

My question is, is it possible to upload app packages using the command line so that I can create a script in the CI to upload app packages to the store? If it is possible, how?

There were lot of tutorials on how to build app packages and deploying to local machine using command line but not on uploading app packages to the store using command line.

Comment: It would be great if the person who down-voted the question could explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article shows you what CmdLets are available: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/appx-packaging-tools

Comment: Thanks Ola. Seems the functionality I'm looking for is not available yet

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP's question

Comment: I'm going to be trying: https://github.com/microsoft/StoreBroker could be what you're looking for.